# Are my home and about links hyperlinking to the right pages?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, nav

I am working on my project from last week and I am not sure that the first two links in my header are hyperlinking back to the index.html (home) and the about.html (about) of my GitHub repo. Also, how can I make the words links without the hyperlink markup decoration of underscore and blue text, (I need them to go to an address but appear as normal black text).

At first I just had them anchored into a nav section but then was toying with a nav-bar set-up and I checked mozilla and w3 but am not finding how to get them the way I need.

```
 <nav>
    <div><img src="https://github.com/paulrt/Sprint-Challenge--User-Interface/blob/master/img/lambda-black.png?raw=true"></img>
    </div>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
 <a href="http://github.com/paulrt/Sprint-Challenge--User-Interface/blob/master/index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="https://github.com/paulrt/Sprint-Challenge--User-Interface/blob/master/about.html">About</a>
```

and here is my css, it has a big hole in it cuz I am stuped

```
header nav {
  width: 65%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 2%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-color: black;
}
header nav about {


}
nav {
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  border: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: black;
```

I need the Home and About button to go to the referenced pages, respectively but also appear as normal non-hyperlinked text. Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated, (and I am like prenatal that is how much of a noob I am so go easy on me if I didn't format or minimize properly please).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS for getting rid of the underline of links and changing their color would look something like this:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black; 
}
```

Note the `a` selector would affect all anchor tags, so you may want to specialize it with a `class` attribute specific to those links:

```
<a class="plain-link" href="...">Link</a>

a.plain-link { ... }
```

Also, another problem you may be facing is your CSS in the original post is only affecting content in `<header>` and `<header><nav>` but not `<header><nav><a>`, So plain text elements like `<span>` or `<p>` would be black, but not links which default to underlined and blue in pretty much all browsers.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but am I able to nest CSS styling or is it just that you include the tags for the elements preceding the curly brackets of the styling you wish to give to said elements?

Comment: Upon adding the a tag to my styling I wound up with a vertical nav list instead of a nav-bar... grrr.... suggestions?

Comment: CSS is added in 3 ways, inline which affects the given element. `<a style="css: here;">` on the same page, nested in style tags: `<style>css: here;<style>`, or on another document linked to the page. Given your newness to CSS, I recommend seeking out tutorials like the ones at codecademy.com and get a better grounding in the principles. This site is more for specific coding problems at an intermediate level or above. Beginners should take the time to learn the basics before asking questions here.